# Circular Doubly Linked List addToHead and print

Tags: java, linked-list

This is my first assignment in java, when i run it, it keeps printing the last node value, i don't know whether it understands that it's circular or not, and don't know where the problem!

```
public class CircularDoublyLinkedList {

public static void main(String argv[]) {
    CircularDoublyLinkedList List = new CircularDoublyLinkedList();
    List.printList();
    List.addToHead(10);
    List.printList();
    List.addToHead(20);
    List.addToHead(30);
    List.printList();

}

class Node {

    Object info;
    Node next, prev;

    Node() {
        info = null;
        next = null;
        prev = null;
    }


    Node(Object el, Node n, Node p) {
        info = el;
        next = n;
        prev = p;
    }
}

private Node head;

CircularDoublyLinkedList() {
    head = null;
}

public void addToHead(Object el) {
    Node tmp = new Node(el, null, null);
    if (head == null) {
        tmp.next = head;
        tmp.prev = head;
        head = tmp;
    }
    head.prev = tmp;
    head.prev.next = tmp;
    tmp.next = head;
    tmp.prev = head.prev;
    head = tmp;

}

public void printList() {

    Node tmp = head;
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.print("empty\n");
        return;
    }
    if (head.next == head) {
        System.out.print(head.info + " <-> " + tmp.info + " \n ");
        return;
    }

    System.out.print(head.info + " <-> ");
    tmp = head.next;
     while (tmp.next != head) {
        System.out.print(tmp.info+ " <-> ");
        tmp = tmp.next;
    }
}
```

This is the output window:

```
empty
10 <-> 10 
30 <-> 20 <-> 10 <-> 10 <-> 10 <-> 10 <-> 10 <-> 10 <-> 10 <-> 10 <-> 10 <-> 10 <->
```

the question is why it does not print the following? where is the problem in the code?

```
empty
10 <-> 10 
30 <-> 20 <-> 10 <-> 30
```

Kindly help, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please clarify what problem you try to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is redundant. I suggest you clean it to understand what is wrong with it.

First of all, I wouldn't use the `Object` type. You can use [Java generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) to make your code cleaner, if you want your class to accept any type of data. Moreover, notice that `Node` is a part of the list, and thus it should not be "shared" with others. You can make it a private class inside the `CircularLinkedList` class.

My suggestion is as follows:

```
public class CircularLinkedList<T> {
    private class Node<T> {
        private T element;
        private Node<T> next;
        private Node<T> previous;

        public Node(T element) {
            this.element = element;
            this.next = null;
            this.previous = null;
        }

        // getters and setters
    }
    private Node<T> head;

    public CircularLinkedList(){
        head = null;
    }
}
```

At this point, in your `CircularLinkedList` class's method you have to add the method that adds an element to the head. Try to sketch the behavior you want on a piece of paper, when: 1) the list is empty; 2) there is just a node in the list; 3) there is more than one element in the list. The result should be as follows:

```
public void addToHead(T element) {
    Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(element);
    if (head == null) {
        // This is the first node you are adding to the list.
        head = newNode;
        head.setNext(head);
        head.setPrevious(head);
    }
    else {
        // Some nodes are already present in your list.

        // Going right.
        newNode.setNext(head);
        newNode.setPrevious(head.getPrevious());

        // Going left.
        newNode.getPrevious().setNext(newNode);
        newNode.getNext().setPrevious(newNode);
        head = newNode;
    }
}
```

To print the list, use the following (again in `CircularLinkedList`):

```
    public void printList() {
        Node<T> temp = head;
        do {
            System.out.print(temp.getElement() + " ");
            temp = temp.getNext();
        } while (temp != head);
    }
```

To print the list in reverse order (again in `CircularLinkedList`):

```
    public void printReverseList() {
        Node<T> temp = head;
        do {
            System.out.print(temp.getElement() + " ");
            temp = temp.getPrevious();
        } while (temp != head);
    }
```

If you run the following code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    // Notice the list declaration where T becomes an actual data type.
    CircularLinkedList<Integer> list = new CircularLinkedList<Integer>();

    list.addToHead(1);
    list.printList();
    System.out.println();
    list.printReverseList();
    System.out.println();

    list.addToHead(2);
    list.addToHead(3);
    list.printList();
    System.out.println();
    list.printReverseList();
}
```

you'll obtain this output:

```
1 

1 

3 2 1 

3 1 2
```

Try to keep your code as clean and readable as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I will apply it step by step and take your notes into consideration. Really thanks much.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please consider tagging it as accepted answer.